# Django & Celery — Routing problems

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, kombu

I'm using Django and Celery and I'm trying to setup routing to multiple queues. When I specify a task's `routing_key` and `exchange` (either in the task decorator or using `apply_async()`), the task isn't added to the broker (which is Kombu connecting to my MySQL database).

If I specify the queue name in the task decorator (which will mean the routing key is ignored), the task works fine. It appears to be a problem with the routing/exchange setup.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Here's the setup:

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'kombu.transport.django',
    'djcelery',
)
BROKER_BACKEND = 'django'
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = "tasks"
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = "topic"
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = "task.default"
CELERY_QUEUES = {
    'default': {
        'binding_key':'task.#',
    },
    'i_tasks': {
        'binding_key':'important_task.#',
    },
}
```

**tasks.py**

```
from celery.task import task

@task(routing_key='important_task.update')
def my_important_task():
    try:
        ...
    except Exception as exc:
        my_important_task.retry(exc=exc)
```

**Initiate task:**

```
from tasks import my_important_task
my_important_task.delay()
```

Comment: How do you pass routing_key? With async_apply?

Comment: I'm using the `delay()` method, which is just a shortcut for `apply_async()`. I'm trying to keep the `routing_key` specification with the task method (via the decorator) instead of when it's called. I have tried passing the key using `apply_async()` instead but I'm getting the same problem.

Comment: delay doesn't accept routing_key keyword. It is a simplified, version of apply_async but they are not the same.

Comment: I'm not passing any routing information when starting the task, I'm specifying it in the task decorator, with the method definition. Please see the code above to see my setup.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that I can just specify the routing/exchange info in the task decorator and it should be respected when called?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You are using the Django ORM as a broker, which means declarations are only stored in memory
(see the, inarguably hard to find, transport comparison table at http://readthedocs.org/docs/kombu/en/latest/introduction.html#transport-comparison)

So when you apply this task with routing_key `important_task.update` it will not be able
to route it, because it hasn't declared the queue yet.

It will work if you do this:

```
@task(queue="i_tasks", routing_key="important_tasks.update")
def important_task():
    print("IMPORTANT")
```

---

But it would be much simpler for you to use the automatic routing feature,
since there's nothing here that shows you need to use a 'topic' exchange,
to use automatic routing simply **remove the settings**:

- `CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE`,
- `CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE`,
- `CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE`
- `CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY`
- `CELERY_QUEUES`

And declare your task like this:

```
@task(queue="important")
def important_task():
    return "IMPORTANT"
```

and then to start a worker consuming from that queue:

```
$ python manage.py celeryd -l info -Q important
```

or to consume from both the default (`celery`) queue and the `important` queue:

```
$ python manage.py celeryd -l info -Q celery,important
```

---

Another good practice is to not hardcode the queue names into the
task and use `CELERY_ROUTES` instead:

```
@task
def important_task():
    return "DEFAULT"
```

then in your settings:

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {"myapp.tasks.important_task": {"queue": "important"}}
```

---

If you still insist on using topic exchanges then you could
add this router to automatically declare all queues the first time
a task is sent:

```
class PredeclareRouter(object):
    setup = False

    def route_for_task(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.setup:
            return
        self.setup = True
        from celery import current_app, VERSION as celery_version
        # will not connect anywhere when using the Django transport
        # because declarations happen in memory.
        with current_app.broker_connection() as conn:
            queues = current_app.amqp.queues
            channel = conn.default_channel
            if celery_version >= (2, 6):
                for queue in queues.itervalues():
                    queue(channel).declare()
            else:
                from kombu.common import entry_to_queue
                for name, opts in queues.iteritems():
                    entry_to_queue(name, **opts)(channel).declare()
CELERY_ROUTES = (PredeclareRouter(), )
```

Comment: Is this issue with queue declarations and exchanges resolved in Celery 3? I'm using the new `CELERY_QUEUES = (Queue(...), ...)` in the settings, does this mean the queues are being declared properly?

Comment: Note: In Celery 4.0 onwards, CELERY_ROUTES has been replaced with CELERY_TASK_ROUTES. Might save someone's time.