# Problems using MongoEngine in Django - raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, mongoengine

I try to get Django 1.5.1 up and running with mongoengine as a second DB backend, but failing big times.

My settings.py includes the following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'DaTaBaSe',                      
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost', 
        'PORT': '3306',                  
    },
    'tracking': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
        'NAME': 'analytics',
    }
}
```

I have a DB router that already takes care of assigning the right app to the mongoDB, which seems to work, as I am seeing the following error in my celery task.

```
File "/mypath/base.py", line 15, in complain
raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
```

ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Any suggestion and idea is welcome.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707287/django-celery-routing-problems

Comment: Unfortunately this is dealing with routing keys within Celery. This seems more like a Django "issue".

Comment: @David Do you get the error only in your task or even in django shell?

Comment: If I try to do this without Celery, I get the same error.


settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'django.db.backends.dummy'` is a dummy implementation Django will use when no `ENGINE` is given or `ENGINE` is an empty string. Every method of the backend API raises `ImproperlyConfigured` (except for `connection.close()` actually)

Comment: I tried setting the DATABASES to dummy backend but still the same error. Inspecting settings.DATABASES return this: 'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
  'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
  'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
  'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
  'HOST': '',
  'NAME': '',
  'OPTIONS': {},
  'PASSWORD': '',
  'PORT': '',
  'TEST_CHARSET': None,
  'TEST_COLLATION': None,
  'TEST_MIRROR': None,
  'TEST_NAME': None,
  'TIME_ZONE': 'UTC',
  'USER': ''}}

Comment: Btw, I'm on Django 1.6.2.